# Customizing the screen of Movieplayer in iPhone

Tags: iphone, movieplayer

I've few doubts regarding movie player app

1. How can I customize the screen size. I want only video or movie to be played only to half the screen and I want to add custom controls buttons to the remaining half of movie player.
2. In movie player example overlay view is there but how to change the name of the button and label in that and I'm unable to do that.

Answer (score 0):

The `MPMovePlayer` UI cannot be modified. It plays fullscreen video, and provides the default controls. There's currently no way to do what you need in the official iPhone SDK.

Answer (score 0):

Use this link for video player customization:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/MoviePlayer_iPhone/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007798

download sample code and modify accordingly.